# FireGento Magesetup: Checkout Agreements are not included on PayPal express review page

Tags: extensions, paypal, ce-1.9.1.0, payment-methods, paypal-standard

FireGento Magesetup: Checkout Agreements are not included on PayPal express review page - can't continue

I run a shop in Germany and due to laws we have to get customers to confirm specific agreements before they can complete the checkout.

In the new PayPal module in Magento CC 1.9.1, we have PayPal Standard configured (which says it includes express checkout) - now when trying to pay with Paypal it always uses the express checkout (at least that is what the URL variable says).

Once you've logged into PayPal you are redirected back to the store, you're presented with a review page with the URL `*/paypal/express/review/` - and a notice that the agreements have to be confirmed before you can continue:

However:

- The Agreement-Checkboxes are not displayed on the page template
- I do not want to use the express checkout, but the standard! Can I disable that somewhere?
- and what is the point of having 2 different PayPal payment types, when one already includes the other?

--- edit ---

My FireGento Magesetup version is 2.1.0 - the github master is at 2.1.1 and the dev is at 2.2.0.

I've seen that the 2.1.0 layout file does not have any paypal references, nor does the 2.1.1 version. The 2.2.0 version  however, defines the following:

```
 <paypal_express_review>
<reference name="paypal.express.review.details">
<action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>downloadable</type><block>downloadable/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</paypal_express_review>
<paypal_express_review_details>
<reference name="paypal.express.review.details">
<action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
<action method="addItemRender"><type>downloadable</type><block>downloadable/checkout_cart_item_renderer</block><template>magesetup/checkout/onepage/review/item.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</paypal_express_review_details>
```

So I'll try and upgrade to the development version 2.2.0 and see it it works then.

--- edit ---

Ok, so the new Version still does not work at all. I've tried adding the checkboxes manually via the local.xml layout file:

```
<paypal_express_review>
<reference name="content">
<!-- add magesetup aggreements -->
<block type="magesetup/checkout_agreements" name="magesetup.checkout.agreements" as="agreements" before="express.review.shipping.method" template="magesetup/checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
<block type="magesetup/checkout_information" name="checkout.onepage.additional" as="additional" after="magesetup.checkout.agreements" template="magesetup/checkout/additional.phtml"/>
</reference>
</paypal_express_review>
```

But the checkboxes being ticked has no effect - it's still the same error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trying and failing I switched to the default RWD theme and see there, the T&C are displayed with checkboxes on the paypal order review page.

So the problem was my 'bought' theme, which had a paypal.xml layout file. I simply renamed it (to: _paypal.xml), to stop it from being loaded and now it all works.

Exactly what in it stopped the TC from displaying I do not yet know. I'll try and figure that out another day.

I'll also give some feedback to the themes developers and hope they will fix this issue in their future themes.

Comment: @tecjam please do it now :-)